# Using Tensorflow Hub with WebHDFS

Tags: python, tensorflow, hadoop, io, tensorflow-hub

I want to place the Tensorflow Hub Model: https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4 on the Hadoop Server, and then use it in my code like so:

```
embed = hub.Module('http:<URL>:<PORT>\<DIR>')
```

I've tried placing the original compressed .tar.gz file up there as well as extracted all its contents and placed them in a separate directory on HDFS. In both cases, I get this error:

```
HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

My WebHDFS API is working fine for other files, and the tensorflow hub Module can also read the files from a directory placed locally, but I need it placed on HDFS, and for some reason it doesnt seem to work up there.

Any fixes?

Answer (score 0):

You can read on tensorflow_hub resolution of paths in https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/docs/hosting.md

In summary and more concretly to host .tar.gz, this means you should be able to pass any HTTPS path that outputs a tar.gz. Example:

```
 hub.Module("https://example.com/dir/filename.tar.gz")
```